# Modulo arithmetic a = 1 mod n

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If I know value of $a$ and also it is known that
$$a \equiv 1 \pmod n$$
how can I calculate value of $n$?

Comment: $n$ can be any divisor of $a-1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks for your answear. But can you explain why this dependency holds?

Comment: that's how Congruence is defined : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain the comment above:

$$a = 1 \mod n$$
$$\iff a = 1 + k \cdot n$$
$$\iff a - 1 = k \cdot n$$
$$\iff n = \frac{a-1}{k}$$

... and $n$ should be an integer, shouldn't it?

Comment: Though, there is nothing wrong with n not being an integer, but to retain a meaningful relationship, k must be an integer. "There exists an integer k such that nk = a - 1" is a more appropriate thing to say.

Comment: Well, how do you define mod for non-integer n?

Comment: "a is congruent to b (mod n) iff there exists an integer k such that a = kn + b" does not require that n be an integer at all (nor a and b). It is only when you require integers that you get statements about divisibility. You may ask why it would ever be useful to take a noninteger as the modulus, but you don't need to look far. As a quick example, if real a and b are congruent (mod 2π), their cosines are equal.

Comment: And if you want mod 0 to remain undefined, requires that k be unique. I personally see no reason to do that, but just to mention.

Comment: OK, I can see that.

Answer (score 2):

Take for example, $15 = 27$ $mod$  $4$. What this basically means is that $15$ and $27$ both leave the same remainder when divided by $4$, that is 3. In that sense they are equal. They also leave the same remainder $1$ when divided by $2$, so therefore $15=27$ $mod$ $2$. 
Can you figure  out now the relation between $a$ and $n$?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Of course I think you wanted to write 15 instead of 17